# Is $\mathbb{R}\times\{0,1\}$ a manifold?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, manifolds

The definition of a $k$-manifold we are given is a set $M\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ such that the following equivalent conditions hold for each $x\in M$:

> - There exists a mapping $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^{n-k}$, continuously differentiable near $x_0$, such that $(Df)_{x_0}=A:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^{n-k}$ is onto and
>   $$ x\in M \iff f(x)=f(x_0)\text{ for all $x$ near $x_0$}$$
> - There exists a local diffeomorphism $\varphi:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ near $x_0$, such that
>   $$ x\in M \iff \varphi(x)\in \mathbb{R}^k\times\{0_{n-k}\}\text{ for all $x$ near $x_0$}$$
> - There exists a permutation $(i_1,\dots,i_n)$ of ${1,\dots,n}$ and a mapping $g:\mathbb{R}^k\to\mathbb{R}^{n-k}$, continuously differentiable near $(x_{0,i_1},\dots,x_{0,i_n})$ such that
>   $$ x\in M \iff g(x_{i_1},\dots, x_{i_k})=(x_{i_{k+1}},\dots,x_{i_n})\text{ for all $x$ near $x_0$}$$

The question is then simply

> Which of the following subsets of $\mathbb{R}^2$ are 1-dimensional manifolds?
>
> [...]
>
> - $M_5=\mathbb{R}\times\{0,1\}$
> - $M_6=\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{Z}$
> - $M_7=\mathbb{R}\times\{1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},\dots\}$

Looking at $M_5$ I think it's not a manifold, as if I look at the permutation $(1,2)$ then as $(0,0),(0,1)\in M$, the function $g(x_1)=x_2$ needs to satisfy both $g(0)=0$ and $g(1)=1$.

Similarly the permutation $(2,1)$ fails as both $(0,0),(1,0)\in M$ which forces $g(x_1)=x_2$ to give both $g(0)=0$ and $g(0)=1$.

Is this reasoning correct? I assume not as then $M_6$ and $M_7$ would fail rather trivially, but what am I misunderstanding here?

Comment: @DietrichBurde As of right now the only definition I know of a manifold is the one I stated, and I have no definition for a manifold with boundary. Does that mean my solution to the problem is correct?

Comment: I'm confused about your answer @Dietrich, the disjoint union of two manifolds is surely a manifold? The real line is a manifold, and two disjoint copies of it next to each other is also a manifold. Any point in $M_5$ has a neighborhood homeomorphic with an open interval, making $M_5$ a 1-dimensional manifold.

Comment: @ZevChonoles Remark $2.1$ [here](http://www.maths.manchester.ac.uk/~tv/Teaching/Differentiable%20Manifolds/2011-2012/2-constructions.pdf) ? Ah, I misread it. It is not $[0,1]$. I should use my glasses.

Comment: @Dietrich: The problem refers to the set $\{0,1\}$, not the closed interval $[0,1]$.

Comment: @ZevChonoles well this does make sense. Can you please explain the errors of my construction then?

Comment: @Nescio: The condition is that $M$ is "cut out" by the solutions with $g$ for all $x$ **close to the point $x_0$**. Slade's answer is correct.

Comment: I am a little confused. You defined the function at first to give the second coordinate, but that would be an $\Bbb{R}^2$ function, while the definition requires an $\Bbb{R}^k$ function... How did you solve it eventually?

Comment: Okay, I just got it. It is about choosing an $\Bbb{R}^2$ element...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your mistake is that you ignored the word "near".  If you take a small enough ball around $(0,0)$, this problem disappears.

Comment: Yep, literally just realized that. But thank you very much :)